# Entity Framework Core, return just related id with Automapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I am developing a REST Api using .netCore 3.1, EF Core and Automapper.

I have the following Entities:

```cs
public class Phase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(800)]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public PhaseCategory PhaseCategory { get; set; }
}
```

and

```cs
public class PhaseCategory
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [MaxLength(50)]
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I created the following DTO for the Rest Api Call /api/Phases

```cs
public class PhaseReadDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public int PhaseCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I have is that in order to make PhaseCategoryId available, I need to query in the following way:

```cs
var phase = _dbContext.Phases.Include(pc => pc.PhaseCategory).ToList();
return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PhaseReadDTO>>(phase));
```

That means that behind the scenes, EF is doing an INNER JOIN that is not needed

```cs
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Description], [p].[Name], [p].[PhaseCategoryId], [p0].[Id], [p0].[Name]  
    FROM [Phases] AS [p]  
    INNER JOIN [PhaseCategories] AS [p0] ON [p].[PhaseCategoryId] = [p0].[Id]
```

But when I do

```cs
var phase = _dbContext.Phases.ToList();
return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PhaseReadDTO>>(phase));
```

The query is what I expect

```cs
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Description], [p].[Name], [p].[PhaseCategoryId]  
            FROM [Phases] AS [p]
```

But the `PhaseCategoryId` is not populated in the response.

Comment: I think if you add a PhaseCategoryId foreign key property on Phase you will get what you need.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: I tried that, but still doing the InnerJoin but with just the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have something like the following line in your mapping configuration -

```cs
.ForMember(d => d.PhaseCategoryId, opt => MapFrom(s => s.PhaseCategory.Id))
```

Right?

Since you don't have a property called `PhaseCategoryId` in your `Phase` model, you are forcing yourself to load the `PhaseCategory` property instead to make the mapping happen, and the -

```cs
Include(pc => pc.PhaseCategory)
```

part of your query is causing the Inner Join.

Add the foreign key property -

```cs
public int PhaseCategoryId { get; set; }
```

in your `Phase` model and define the mapping configuration as simply -

```cs
CreateMap<Phase, PhaseReadDTO>();
```

Then you can query without the `Include` part and still have the `PhaseCategoryId` in the response.

Comment: Thanks , I thought a similar approach at the beginning but i was worried about generating a duplicate field in the DB. I checked EF docs and tried and works as a charm !!
Thanks for the help !